# JAVA nested for loop beginners

Tags: java

```
public class MultiplicationTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int E = 2;

        for(int i =1;i<=9;i++){
            for(int j=0; j<1 ; j++){
                System.out.print("2xi" E * i);//problem!!!
            }
            System.out.println();
        }


    }
```

I don't get why I am getting errors...

Comment: You appear to be missing a `+` sign. `("2xi" + E * i);`

Comment: In future questions, please post the complete error message.

Comment: `System.out.print("2xi"+(E * i));`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

As the comments said change:

```
System.out.print("2xi" E * i);//problem!!!
```

to

```
System.out.print("2xi " + E * i);
```

Comment: Best to just let this question be closed and die a natural death. It's not going to help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Use the concatenation operator '+' to combine string and result:

```
public class MultiplicationTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int E = 2;

        for(int i =1;i<=9;i++){
            for(int j=0; j<1 ; j++){
                System.out.print("2xi" + (E * i));//problem!!!
            }
            System.out.println();
        }


    }
```